# Aptana studio does not start without any error on windows 10

Tags: windows, ide, aptana3

OS: Windows 10 x64

Aptana ver:3.6.1

When i try to start Aptana Studio nothing happens, no error, no new proccess in Task Manager, nothing. When i check log in workspace nothing there, i tried to delete file .snap in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources (solution founded in google) but it not exist.

Earlier it works perfectly ;/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

> So simply download the current x86-JDK, install it and try running Aptana again, that should do the trick!

source: https://steps0x29a.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/getting-aptana-studio-3-to-start-on-windows-7-x64/